# UIAutomation - Scroll and Text Issues

Tags: c#, textbox, scroll, ui-automation

I made a small uiautomation app that scrolls through a forms windows searching for a specific richtextbox. Once it finds the richtextbox, it would extract the text and verify against a constant. I already coded the entire program but I have two issues:

1. The FindAll function sometimes misses the textbox. I believe its due to scrolling too fast since if I step through my app, it works everytime.
2. The TextPattern applied to the richtextbox provides me with DocumentRange.GetText function. However, it doesn't retrieve any returns/new lines.

Is there anything I can implement to consistently catch my textbox without slowing down the scroll?

Is there any option to extract the text with returns/new lines included? I can consider Copy/Paste since some of my textboxes aren't selectable.

---

Update 1/19/2015
For problem 1, I placed a couple Thread.Sleep(500) . I'm not sure where it would indicate the pane is still loading due to scrolling.

For problem 2, I found out that the textboxes I thought were unselectable are selectable. However, I still don't want to use the copy option since one event that changes my projects focus will copy the wrong location. I barely keep the SendKeys option as it is.

Comment: FindAll can sometimes miss the element if it's not created or become visible yet. This is a standard delay/wait problem for UI automation.

Comment: @VasilyRyabov Is there some indicator for elements still loading? If I run a FindFirst for any item, would it return null if the elements are still loading?

Comment: Invisible (but already created) elements cannot be found by FindAll / FindFirst. You need some sufficient pause or finding several times with some reasonable time interval.